# Can't get `Include` to work with EF core , without FK

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables in SQL server without a FK :

[image]

So each `Image` has many `Comments`.

Using this command I've created scaffolded files :

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
>   "Server=sff-pc;Database=IMG;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t **Images** -t
>   **comments**  --context-dir Context -c MyContext -f

Here are the generated files :

```
 public partial class Images
    {
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public Guid ImgGuid { get; set; }
        public string ImgExtension { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datecreated { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public decimal? Size { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public int? VotesUp { get; set; }
        public int? VotesDown { get; set; }
        public int ImgType { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Comments
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public int UserId1 { get; set; }
    public string CommentTxt { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:**

Using those generated classes and this [full context file](https://gist.github.com/RoyiNamir/3852b1af0a917b0cb8ad0ef09e62fc6a), How can I get each `Image` and `Include` its `comments`?

What have I tried :

I've tried adding the ForeignKey attribute :

```
 public partial class Comments
    {
        public int CommentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Images")]          <--------------Here
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public int UserId1 { get; set; }
        public string CommentTxt { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

And to run this :

```
        var context = new MyContext();
        var result = context.Images.Include("Comments"); //exception

         foreach (var a in result)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(a);
         }
```

Exception :

*The property 'Comments' is not a navigation property of entity type 'Images'*

Comment: are you expecting the list of comments in `result`?

Comment: @Neville Nazerane anything. I just want to get the images left join with comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[ForeignKey("Images")]` over your fk "Images" is expected to be a **navigation property** inside your `Comments` class not the name of your `DbSet` property in your `DbContext`. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types) and [relationships here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). In the case of your code based on the definition of your `Comments` class, you will need to have a property `Images`.

```
[ForeignKey("Images")]          
public int ImageId { get; set; }
public Images Images { get; set; } // ForeignKey attribute points to this
```

While the above shows how you can use `[ForeignKey("Images")]`, I would recommend making the property's name `Image` instead of `Images`. Not only will it be a better explanatory name, but it would also make the `[ForeignKey("Image")]` unnecessary. EF would automatically map `Image` to Image**id** by naming convention.

Based on the way you are using to access comments using `context.Images.Include("Comments")`, you seem to be trying to access the list of comments under an image. However, if you notice your `result` variable would be a `IQueryable` of `Images`. To achieve this, you will need to add a navigation property into your `Images` class.

```
public IEnumerable<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
```

Since you have already mapped your foreign key, your mapping is implicit between `ImageId` and `Comments`. You can, however, use `InverseProperty` attribute to be safe (check the [relationships link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) for more info). Once this is done you can use the following code:

```
var result = context.Images.Include(i => i.Comments);
```

Comment: I did exactly as you told me , but still exception: https://i.imgur.com/5gTtUiv.jpg

Comment: Comments should be an ICollection instead of an IEnumerator

Comment: My bad. `IEnumerable<Comments>` not `IEnumerator<Comments>`. You can also use `ICollection` as @DevilSuichiro suggested. I did replicate your issue when I used `IEnumerator` instead. If there are still issues check this working demo https://github.com/neville-nazerane/ef-issuetest